# ClassNotFoundException on Jersey2Config (io.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig)

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I have configured my project for swagger, my project is maven, struts, hibernate. I have added dependency in pom

```
<!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

and web.xml is like this:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>io.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>api.version</param-name>
            <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
            <param-value>/PatientApp/services/</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

core filters added as well:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

But when i try to run the project it gives me error. stack trace is under fellow:

```
Oct 14, 2015 5:40:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet Jersey2Config as unavailable
Oct 14, 2015 5:40:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /PatientApp threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig
```

Comment: If you can post the entire stack trace it should be easier to help

Comment: Were you able to folve this? If yes, how?

Comment: did'nt @JohannesJander

Answer (score 0):

can u check ur following parameter is correct

1. List item

   ```
   <init-param>
       <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
       <param-value>/PatientApp/services/</param-value>
   </init-param>
   ```

usually it is like that
        
            swagger.api.basepath
            http://localhost:8080/api

- do u have servlet mapping in web.xml?  2
- Change the version of the jar, try this 

    com.wordnik
    swagger-jersey-jaxrs_2.10
    1.3.12

Comment: All tried but failed... 1- checked it is correct, modified as well but failed 2- There's no <servlet-mapping> for this servlet as it is only used for initialization and doesn't actually expose any interface. 3- version changed as well but same – @ashaar-riaz

Comment: class not found exception now finished, now need more configuration @ashaar-riaz

Comment: completed but failed to add authorization header, therefore i am unable to access api in swagger ui.

Comment: I am facing similar issue: Works fine from localhost. as soon as i upload on remote host, it fails to work.: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlGeneratorImpl.createResponse(WadlGeneratorImpl.java:198)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared how rest of the your entries in web.xml look like. Also i did not have any exclusions in pom.xml. You can take a look at my web.xml from option 2 below to see where your config differs.

There are two ways to configure JerseyJaxrsConfig

### 1. Inside web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>io.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>api.version</param-name>
        <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8080/jax_rs/rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

### 2. Inside a custom JaxrsConfig class

Second way is to create a Config Java class and point to it from web.xml. You can read that in details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35905415/5076414