# Swagger and web.xml

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs, resteasy, swagger

I am trying to get swagger working with my java rest api.
I am following the [swagger documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-RESTEasy-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5#configure-and-initialize-swagger). However, I am unable to get swagger to work.

For example, according to the docs, I should get a json file from swagger - but regardless of what url I try, I never get it.

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>
    io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource,
    io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers,
    com.my.service.rest.handler.JsonParseExceptionHandler, 
    com.my.service.rest.handler.IllegalArgumentExceptionHandler, 
    com.my.service.rest.handler.JsonMappingExceptionHandler, 
    com.my.service.rest.handler.RuntimeExceptionHandler
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>io.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig</servlet-class> 
    <init-param>
        <param-name>api.version</param-name>
        <param-value>0.1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8080/indicatorsService</param-value>

        <!-- also not working <param-value>http://localhost:8080/docs</param-value> -->
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JbossServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JbossServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Based on the swagger documentation, if I go to http://localhost:8080/indicatorsService/swagger.json, I should get the swagger json - instead I get the following error

```
Error in handling REST request. ExpectionMessage: Could not find resource for relative : /swagger.json of full path: http://localhost:8080/indicatorsService/swagger.json: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for relative : /swagger.json of full path: http://localhost:8080/indicatorsService/swagger.json
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchChildren(RootSegment.java:360) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchRoot(RootSegment.java:374) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchRoot(RootSegment.java:367) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:307) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:173) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:118) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_85]
```

thank you.

Comment: Hello, does your server start without errors? Do you see that it is registering the endpoints in the logging?
Did you generate your Java server based on the swagger-codegen tool? If so, could you share the Swagger file you ran the codegen with?
If not, maybe you could run the codegen tool and compare the differences?
To me it looks like your http://localhost:8080/indicatorsService/swagger.json path might be incorrect - maybe it should be http://localhost:8080/indicatorsService/api/swagger.json

Comment: Hi, there are no errors when deploying. The service works fine. I did not generate the java server from swagger. I am just trying to generate swagger docs for an existing service. I have tried the url you suggested, and many others - without success. Thanks

Comment: @Integrating Stuff - thanks for the suggestion about reviewing a generated swagger service. I have been doing this, but cannot see anything obviously wrong. It would be nice if there was some error to help point the direction, but there isnt. I dont know if it is an issue with RestEasy, or Jboss, or something else. I have tried all logical urls. And now am just guessing.

Comment: you can check how i did this with swagger and jax-rs at http://stackoverflow.com/a/35905415/5076414

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar configuration in an application of mine, except that I use Jersey 2 instead of RestEasy.

I checked my `web.xml` file, which is configured in a similar way (except for the servlet class, which is specialized for Jersey 2). Here is an excerpt:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>jax-rs-ws</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>com.jeff.MyJerseyApp</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jax-rs-ws</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>swagger-servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>api.version</param-name>
    <param-value>1.1.0</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
    <param-value>http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/rest</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Here are a few hints:

- My Jersey servlet is mapped to the `/rest/*` pattern. The global root `/*` may be fine too but let's go on...
- The base path defined in the Swagger servlet includes the same `/rest` URI within my application.

Moreover, the URL I must use to retrieve the JSON-structured API info is the following:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/rest/api-docs
```

whose URI starts with the same `/rest` path. This brings me to think that you should use the following address:

```
http://localhost:8080/indicatorsService/api-docs
```

I hope I guessed right...

Comment: Thanks @JeffMorin - yes your setup does look similar, and I have tried your suggestions, and every other seemingly logical urls. Alas, nothing is working.

Comment: Sorry about that... I will do some more investigations and if I find something else I will notify you.

Comment: Thanks Jeff - much appreciated.